# What is the distribution of the Wilcoxon signed-ranked test statistic?

Tags: distributions, wilcoxon-signed-rank

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) notes, "$W$ follows a specific distribution with no simple expression". Unencouraging as that sounds, its mean and variance are respectively $0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{N_r}k^2$. I'm thus guessing $W\sim\sum_{k=1}^{N_r}kY_k$ for iids $Y_k$ of mean 0, variance 1. However, if I'm right the $Y_k$ aren't Gaussian, as then $W$ would be too.

Despite the title, my question is really what distribution these $Y_k$ have. I realise $W$ won't have a "neat" pdf, though its characteristic function would be nicer; if each $Y_k$ has cf $\phi(t)=\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2))$, $W$'s cf will be $\prod_{k=1}^{N_r}\phi(kt)$.

Comment: What is the basis of this guess?

Comment: @Glen_b By analogy with the $\chi_k^2$ test statistic being a sum of $k$ iids, only in this case considering the variance we'd need a $k$ factor as well.

Comment: The signed-rank distribution (and rank sum distribution also) does not have a closed form, but relies on a recurrence relationship. An article by Bellera &Co. has some good graphical visualizations about how the signed-rank (and rank-sum) distributions approach normality. Bellera, C. A., Julien, M., and Hanley, J. A. (2010). [Normal approximations to the distributions of the Wilcoxon statistics: Accurate to what *n*?](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n2/bellera.pdf) Graphical insights. *Journal of Statistics Education*, 18(2):1–17.

Comment: @J.G. If you look at Alexis' reference, just keep in mind that it's using a different definition of the statistic than you have; the test and the probabilities associated with various outcomes are the same but the test statistic there is a scaled and shifted version of yours. It's easy to convert between them if you're aware of the difference in the two statistics, but otherwise it may lead to some confusion

Answer (score 5):

I'll give an outline of what's involved.

Let's look at the original (no ties) case. Note that a specific rank either contributes $R_k$ or $-R_k$ to the sum (with sign chosen randomly under the null). Let $S_k$ be the sign of the $k$th observation (/difference in a paired test) -- i.e. $-1$ if the difference is $<0$ and $+1$ otherwise, and without loss of generality assume the data are in rank order ($R_k=k$).

Then $W=\sum_k k S_k$. With a fixed set of ranks, each term in the sum is independent but is not identically distributed.

It's easy enough to write down the distribution for small $n$ by simply considering the possibilities.

e.g. with $n=3$ observations (pair differences in a paired test) the signs are

```
+ + +
+ + -
+ - +
+ - -
- + +
- + -
- - +
- - -
```

(where `-` indicates $S_i=-1$, etc. You can then simply multiply each sign by the rank (1 for the first column, 2 for the second, etc) and record the values of the statistics:

```
1+2+3=6, 1+2-3=0, 1-2+3=2, 1-2-3=-4, -1+2+3=4, -1+2-3=-2, -1-2+3=0, -1-2-3=-6
```

which is $1/8$ probability on $\pm 2,\pm 4,\pm 6$ and $1/4$ probability on $0$.

Automated complete enumeration is fairly practical for small $n$ -- say up to 20-25 or so (which is already to the point where we can use the asymptotic approximation fairly happily). We can extend this a little further by focusing only on the tail.

However, efficient combinatorial algorithms exist for computing these distributions in samples that are not huge - n=1000 takes less than a second on a modest laptop, and n=3000 -- which has 4.5 million values in it -- takes less than ten seconds (i.e. they work well out to far, far beyond where the asymptotics "kick in" effectively).

[image: Plot of pmf of W under the null for n=3,6,10 and 100]

**The moment generating function and characteristic function**

You could indeed write the mgf or the cf of these $kS_k$ terms and hence of the sum (I think the mgf of $S_k$ is $\cosh(t)$, the cf would be $\cos(t)$ but I'll let you check that, and you can get the mgf or cf of $kS_k$ from $M_{bX}(t)=M_X(bt)$, so I think the mgf of $kS_k$ should be $\cosh(kt)$, and similarly $\cos(kt)$ for the cf). The mgf of the sum is the product of the mgfs (and similarly for the cf), so we can at least get to that point fairly easily.

**Asymptotics**

Under the null, the mean of your statistic $W$ is $0$ (it's a sum of terms whose means are all $0$) and the variances of the components are $k^2 \text{Var}(S_k)=k^2$ (because the variance of an equally probable $\pm 1$ is $1$), so $\text{Var}(W)=\sum_k k^2$.

However, you don't need to use the characteristic function to show asymptotic normality, since you can just rely on the Lindeberg version of CLT; showing the variance condition holds is easy.

Comment: Thanks; this is the result I inferred from the paper Alexis shared.

Answer (score 0):

For I.I.D $Y_{k}$, the Gaussian assumption will not matter much in the limit. Even when random variables are independent with different distributions, they converge to a normal distribution in the limit under some regularity conditions. Please see  any standard large sample theory book for a reference (My illustration comes from section 2.7 in 'Elements of Large Sample Theory' by E.L. Lehmann. A picture of the relevant theorem is attached below)

[image]

Comment: I'm aware a Normal distribution will be approximately valid for large $k$. What I'm asking is what distribution $Y_1$ has.